# VBA/Excel - Multiple website scrape returns duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

I have been scraping data from multiple websites and pulling into excel the inner text of a specific tag from each of those. The code goes as follow:

```
For Each x In Range("C2:C30")
If x <> Blank Then

    With Web
        .navigate Cells(x.Row, 3).Value
    End With
    Do While Web.Busy
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set Doc = Web.document
    Set AllClass = Doc.getElementsByClassName("name")

    On Error Resume Next
    vName = AllClass(0).innerText

    Cells(x.Row, 1).Value = vName

    Next x
```

Now this works, however, it randomly returns duplicate results. It seems to not properly load the entire page before pulling in the information although I do have the 'DoEvents' inserted at the beginning of the loop. For example, I should be getting the following information from five websites:

> 1. Bob
> 2. John
> 3. Jane
> 4. Joe
> 5. Hank

Instead I get something like this (which randomly varies):

> 1. Bob
> 2. John
> 3. John
> 4. Joe
> 5. Hank

And running the macro again would randomly yield:

> 1. Bob
> 2. John
> 3. Jane
> 4. Jane
> 5. Jane

I would suspect that this has to do with IE scraping the data from the previous page because it couldn't finish loading the website. No idea how to fix this..

Thanks!

Comment: Do not only check Busy but also ReadyState (it should be 4 when page loading has finished)

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly now! :)
I wasn't aware of ReadyState. I was under the impression that Busy would of done the job!

Comment: You should clear vName just before you set its value - that would make it more obvious if you fail to get a new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not only check Busy but also ReadyState (it should be 4 when page loading has finished)

Comment: You can also wait for DocumentCompleted event.